# How to bring back old Armature Layer display from pre-4.0?

Tags: animation, armature, interface

I'm a long-time animator who is slowly transitioning to 4.0+ and the new bone collection UI is awful. Takes way too much space for no reason, and while I'm sure it's useful if you see the rig for first time and need to know what is where, once you use the rig for a while the old one with the boxes is way better and more compact and I know where everything is.

**NEW:**

[image: new UI]

**OLD:**

[image: old UI]

Please tell me there's a way to revert it back to way it was. Why is that not just a toggle? :/